# How to use select to choose from x files, that contain lists, needed to run set of commands against, in this case curl

Tags: bash, curl, select

I have about 100 lists of URLs used for health checking (200, 300,400,500) but cannot figure out the terminology to ask the question. In advance, I apologize.

I want to use a list to choose on of the identified list files, containing the URLS, and then run curl against it to get my results. Currently, Im stumped.

If I call out the file implicitly, I can get things to work. If I use a select againt the listing of files to choose from, I can get that file and do a simple 'cat' of the result and get the URL's in it successfully.

I cannot seem to do the select, get the file into its variable and then make the next move to the loop to run thru those items in the chosen file successfully.

Im embarrased that its making a mess out of my hair.

works

```
select f in *.lst; do echo $f
done
```

Does not work in any way or format

```
select f in *.lst;
for i in (cat $f); do curl $i
done

 bash -x ./test.sh 
+ select f in '*.lst'
1) availability_health_check.lst      3) facility_service_health_check.lst
2) explorer_health_check.lst          4) mobile_service_health_check.lst
#? 1
+ echo availability_health_check.lst
availability_health_check.lst
```

Comment: Have a read through https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 to properly read the lines of a file.

Comment: You'd need to tell us how the files (URLs in the files?) are to be selected for checking . As it stands, your script snippet looks fine if you want to run all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing a `do` and `done` for your `select` statement. I believe you want something like this:

```
select f in *.lst; do
        for i in $(cat $f); do
                curl "$i"
        done
done
```

This will allow you to select a file, then curl is ran on each line in the selected file. Add an `exit 0` after the for loop if want the script to exit after you've selected a file.

Comment: BINGO!!!

Thanks. Sometimes it is hard to see the trees for the forest.